# Composing URL from single hierarchical table of pages with URL parts in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, hierarchical-data

I have a single page table with 4 fields;

```
ID | ParentID | Name | URL Part
```

ParentID is nullable. Null ParentID records represent top level pages.

The URL part field contains only what the URL would be for that page. When a record contains a ParentID, the parent's URL part would be prepended to the child's. There maybe be up to 4 levels on nesting.

E.g. 2 rows;

```
ID | ParentID |        Name        |    URLPart
---+----------+--------------------+-----------------
 1 |   NULL   |      Wildlife      |     wildlife
 2 |    1     | Otters and beavers |  otters-beavers
```

I would like to get the value `/wildlife/otters-beavers` for row 2 in an SQL Query without a cursor. Slashes are omitted from the URL parts but need to separate the url parts in the combined column.

I started doing this in LINQ but it's a bit messy so hopefully can move it to the database.

Appreciate any help,

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: if you share your linq code, you help us to help you ;).

Comment: I decided the database was the place I wanted to do this. My linq is spaghetti not worth sharing :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [Recursive Common Table Expression](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE 
(   ID INT NOT NULL,
    ParentID INT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    URLPart VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

INSERT @T (ID, ParentID, Name, URLPart) 
VALUES 
    (1, NULL, 'Wildlife', 'Wildlife'), 
    (2, 1, 'Otters and beavers', 'otters-beavers'), 
    (3, 1, 'Canines', 'canines'), 
    (4, 3, 'dogs', 'dogs');

WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  ID, ParentID, Name, URLPart, RecursionLevel = 1, FullURL = URLPart
    FROM    @T
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  cte.ID, 
            t.ParentID, 
            cte.Name, 
            cte.URLPart, 
            cte.RecursionLevel + 1,
            CAST(t.URLPart + '/' + cte.FullURL AS VARCHAR(255))
    FROM    CTE
            INNER JOIN @T AS t 
                ON t.ID = cte.ParentID
)
SELECT  ID, Name, URLPart, FullURL
FROM    CTE
WHERE   NOT EXISTS 
        (   SELECT 1 
            FROM    CTE AS CTE2 
            WHERE   CTE2.ID = CTE.ID 
            AND     CTE2.RecursionLevel > CTE.RecursionLevel
        )
ORDER BY ID;
```